# migration to hibernate 4 + spring 4.2.2: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

I'm migrating to spring 4.2.2.RELEASE and hibernate 5 and get following exception:

The exception also occurs in hibernate 4:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'NotificationService' defined in class path resource [business-context.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'lovDao' threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1518)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    ... 127 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'lovDao' threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:121)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    ... 135 more
:org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException:Failed properties: Property 'lovDao' threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:121)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

this is the definition of the 'lovDao' bean:

```
<bean id="ListOfValuesDao" class="be.fgov.just.cjr.dao.core.ListOfValuesDaoImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

and relevant portions of the dao-context.xml:

```
<!-- Enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
<bean id="transactionManager" name="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<!-- Enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<context:component-scan base-package="be.fgov.just.cjr.dao" />

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="be.fgov.just.cjr.model"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">be.fgov.just.cjr.oracle.OracleDialectWithXmlTypeSupport</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.JtaTransactionFactory</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Now, this is the class definition of the lovDao:

```
@Transactional 
//@Repository removed for testing (didn't work)
public class ListOfValuesDaoImpl extends GenericDaoImpl implements ListOfValuesDao {
```

and also GenericDaoImpl is transactional

```
@Transactional
//@Repository removed for testing (didn't work)
public class GenericDaoImpl implements GenericDao {
```

Why doesn't lovDao can't obtain a transaction-synchronized Session?

ListOfValuesDaoImpl wasn't Transactional at first but threw the exact same exception; GenericDaoImpl was.

also GenericDao is Transactional: (not anymore)

```
//@Transactional removed for testing (didn't work)
//@Repository removed for testing (didn't work)
public interface GenericDao {
```

I know that similar questions are asked around SO but I already tried quite some pointers and read quite some guides but nothing seemed to work...

thanks for pointers/help/critical remarks ;)

S.

edit:

the sessionFactory is set in GenericDaoImpl...:

```
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Autowired
public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}
```

(I added the @Qualifier("sessionFactory") because IntelliJ complained about multiple beans (which in fact pointed to the same bean))
-> I checked whether the dao-context.xml is used multiple times but it isn't

...and (in that same class) the session is obtained like this:

```
public Session getSession() {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}
```

edit 2 (reaction on edit of answer of GUISSOUMA Issam):

I also have beans like this one:

```
<bean id="DossierDao" class="be.fgov.just.cjr.dao.dossier.DossierDaoImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    <property name="lovDao" ref="ListOfValuesDao"/>
    <property name="dossierValidator" ref="DossierValidator"/>
</bean>
```

What do I do with those?

(they reference ListOfValuesDao...)
(@Autowiring doesn't seem to help (according to IntelliJ) it doesn't find a reference to a ListOfValuesDao)

-> the same exception also occurs when I removed:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="be.fgov.just.cjr.dao" />
```

ps: thanks for your persistence in helping me, problem is I can't test out stuff now because I write this from home (and can't reach the environment on the office :( 
-> if you give a couple of pointers I'll be able to try them out tomorrow but I can only depend on the IDE's output for the present moment :(
-> I'll try to give as much information as possible

I also have this in GenericDaoImpl:

```
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Autowired
public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}
```

in combination with:

```
<bean id="GenericDao" class="be.fgov.just.cjr.dao.GenericDaoImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

based on the edit of the answer I suppose this can cause the problem?
(I can only check for sure tomorrow morning...)

edit 3: I've gotten quite some new information and instead of appending it all here I [created a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33613407/hibernate-4-spring-4-2-2-could-not-obtain-transaction-synchronized-session-for)...

Answer (score 1):

Add @Repository annotation to your DAO.

remove this declaration

```
<bean id="ListOfValuesDao" class="be.fgov.just.cjr.dao.core.ListOfValuesDaoImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

from your XML

because you have this:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="be.fgov.just.cjr.dao" />
```

Make sure your package is scanned only once(declared on in one xml file)

Comment: nope, didn't solve the problem (same exception) (I also added (a)Repository to the parents which had (a)Transactional to no avail...) ((a) means @ but the comment box doesn't like that ;)

Comment: how do you get your session from sessionFactory?

Comment: I added it in the edit also: IntelliJ complained about the sessionFactory bean used multiple times (but upon inspection these references pointed to the same bean)

Comment: remove this declaration <bean id="ListOfValuesDao" class="be.fgov.just.cjr.dao.core.ListOfValuesDaoImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

Comment: I have beans which depend on ListOfValuesDao; (in the same package) what do I do with those?

Comment: Hey GUISSOUMA Issam, thanks for your help once again; good question ;) I found out that this issue was caused whilst the lovDao was injected into another bean and was accessed and no datasource was around in that context: I posted this as [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33613407/hibernate-4-spring-4-2-2-could-not-obtain-transaction-synchronized-session-for) there they advised to use spring boot and now I'm implementing this solution; it doesn't work yet so I can't answer the question for the present moment; could be I run into some other issue still...  keep you posted...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what 'fixed' this issue but I do get a:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException:Unable to locate current JTA transaction
```

exception now (so this question is resolved, I hope (I'll set my answer as correct answer if I don't get this exception again through the migrating process)

I think the "Unable to locate current JTA transaction" exception is due to my configuration as described above + the addition of:

```
<prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">jta</prop>
```

to the:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="be.fgov.just.cjr.model"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
```

But I'm not sure whether this is an exception on top of the questioned one or below...

I not necessarily completely followed GUISSOUMA Issam but he gave me some good pointers so I'll upvote his response...

to be continued...